# Signal on top of PWR line

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, pwm, signal, signal-processing

See edits at bottom:

I'm trying to design a network of circuits (see example below), in which a modular circuit (non-static, can be change, with high variability in current draw) is connected on any of several PCB positions, and while drawing power, can detect the position it is located.

Min Current: 0.1mA, Max Current: 600mA

Due to mechanical constraints, no additional connections (i.e. only PWR, GND) can be made between PCB position #, & modular circuit.

My idea is to PWM (100Hz, could be higher) the PWR line, and use a high-pass filter to eliminate lower freq's. Modular circuit will check for what freq removed.

Any other advice is also welcome,

*******in response to comment about not being clear:******

Maybe to simplify imagine using a Smartphone USB Charger, and connecting custom split cable to several PCB board (as many as 24), with battery connectors. Then modular circuits are attached to battery connectors and they need to know which position their in.

### [image: Position Circuit Example, Voltage follower Question Diagram]

Based on suggestion by @WhatRoughBeat, i've added another possible schematic, of a voltage divider, instead of pulse train.

[image: pulse train replaced with voltage divider]

Please Note: in original question/schematic I made some error, the following have been corrected:
(1) schematic, Switched from low-pass to high pass of using low-pass filter;

(2) schematic, Switched from plain diodes, probably schottky

(3) added current max/min

(4) lower PWM from 1KHz to 100Hz, to help reduce EMI

(5) modified title

Comment: All high-level communication is done wireless-ly

Comment: I'm not sure that you have adequately explained what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As Andy aka said you should really explain more about what you want to achieve. But to briefly anwser your question, the main differences I can think of are voltage/current handling, distortions and frequency limits.

Comment: @Andy aka, sorry for bad explanation, not sure how to improve. I typically deal with strictly DC, and was day dreaming in physics courses when they dealt with AC. Edited circuit to hopefully help

Comment: @Golaž I've tried to improve explanation

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear why you think your circuit ought to work, but I'll give it a try. You seem to think that by passing a pulse train through different low-pass filters, you can change the frequency of the signal, and then use zener diodes to convert this back to a pulse train. The simple answer is, no, you can't do that in any useful sense. You might try something like this, though.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL2IKi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "additional circuits" would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRpiZo.png)</sup>

The high duty cycle maximizes the effective power supply voltage to the additional units, but between the FET IR drop and the diode drop in the final stage, I doubt you can get better than 4.5 volts for an initial 5 volts supply. Depending on what components you use, the drop might be as much as 1 volt.

Note that this approach does have a big drawback - EMI. By chopping your power supply voltage you pretty much guarantee that your system will radiate like crazy. Shielding, both of boxes and cables, will be important.

Comment: thanks for input, not very knowledge about AC. I was concerned about EMI. I've changed the Pulse Train to Voltage divider, with that work?